# Include php file via Ajax and display on page

Tags: php, ajax

I was wondering if there is any way to include a php file after an AJAX call and display that included file in my page as response.

For example this is an ajax call:

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:  "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "select="+selected,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#here").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is what i tried in php but i got not result displayed on my html:

```
if(isset($_POST['select'])){
    $post= $_POST['select'];

    $class = ClassName::find_by_id($post);

    $sql = " sp_SQLStoredproc {$class->id} ";
    if($class->hasRows($sql)){
        include("include.php");
    }

}
```

Is there any way to display my included file in my html?

I tried to change my success response from Ajax `$("#here").html(data);` to `$("#here").load(data);` but it returned the whole page.

Any suggestions will help.

**UPDATE: Inside the include.php file exist a long html code and some class methods**

**PS. Please don't mentioned that script is not safe, I know is just an example script.**

Thank you in advance

Comment: where in the php is the returned output? what's inside include. php?

Comment: @GuyLouzon lets say that inside include there is a long html code and some php methods of this class

Comment: @Maria What is in the data object in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the success data you need to return the data which you want to be included. And remember `php` will not work in `html` except it is action call. You can have `php` file for this since it has the `html` support also.

Also you need to remember, before setting the success data to the element it's better to console the value and make sure you are getting the correct data.

```
if(isset($_POST['select'])){
    $post= $_POST['select'];

    $class = ClassName::find_by_id($post);

    $sql = " sp_SQLStoredproc {$class->id} ";
    if($class->hasRows($sql)){
        return include("include.php");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set all your "include.php" html in buffers and then you need to echo your content into console.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['select'])){
        $post= $_POST['select'];

        $class = ClassName::find_by_id($post);

        $sql = " sp_SQLStoredproc {$class->id} ";
        if($class->hasRows($sql)){
            ob_starts();
            include("include.php");
            $include = ob_get_contents();
            echo $include;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21167886)

Comment: @Haider without explanation this answer is not much useful and will be deleted.