# AJAX response with include statement in a while loop

Tags: php, include

I have an AJAX call to a PHP file where I get the data from MySQL database in a while loop. Then I am returning this back as response. So far so good.

Part of working sample PHP file called by AJAX looks like this. **EDIT:** `echo` in this sample is not a part of the `some-HTML-included-file.php` file in the second example.

```
... mysql commands ...
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo 'some HTML here' . $data['id'];
}
```

Now because the HTML (here in while loop) is quite big in my application and I use it also in another files, I have it in **separate file** and just **including it**.

So the result looks like this

```
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo include 'inc/some-HTML-included-file.php';
}
```

It kind of works, but it also returns `true` for successful include which becomes `1` in resulting HTML.

My question is, how to do this the correct way, so I get the result without additional `1`s.

**Note:** I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871622/include-php-file-via-ajax-and-display-on-page), but this obviously does not work in a loop.

Comment: Since the file itself already echoes data, just `include` instead of `echo include`. You don't need to output the result of the include command! Or do what most people would and implement this as a function which returns a string of HTML, rather than a raw include which directly echoes content - that approach is very obsolete.

Comment: @ADyson sorry for misleading. The echo is not a part of the file which is included. It is there just because it does not work without it. I edited the question.

Comment: @ADyson now I have tried only `include` in a `while` loop and it works. I bet I have tried that before, but now it works.

Comment: `it works`...then surely `some-HTML-included-file.php` must be echoing some data somewhere within it? Or else how do you see any results?

Comment: I have tested it and the included file can contain for example only `<div>hi</div>` and it works too. Maybe it is called echoing (without actually using `echo`) and I just don't know the right terminology.

Comment: Ah yes if you put code outside a PHP `<?php ... ?>` block then that is automatically counted as static content and will be output without needing any commands. That's true in any php file, not just when you use it with `include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file itself already echoes data, just use `include` instead of `echo include`. You don't need to output the result of the `include` command!

Or do what most people would and implement this as a function which returns a string of HTML, rather than a raw `include` which directly echoes content - that approach is very obsolete.

For example:

```
function getRowContent($data)
{
  return 'some HTML here' . $data['id'];
}

while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo getRowContent($data);
}
```

(Obviously to share that function across PHP scripts you can put the function in a separate PHP file and then `include_once` the file at the top of any script in which you want to use it, so that the function is then available to be called when needed.)

Comment: thanks. This could be the way, but it works also only with `include` itself. May bad, sorry.